# WSS 3.0 : Retrieve user permission rights

Tags: security, sharepoint, permissions

may I know how can i retrieve user's permission rights from its userid and group name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the SharePoint PM responsible for permissions management

Permissions on what?

Anything that implements ISecurableObject (SPWeb, SPList, SPItem..) will expose 'RoleAssignments'. If you're just looking for a specific user's permissions you can use DoesUserHavePermissions to check for a specific mask